# Преобразование хэш-таблицы в CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

Есть пример кода:

```
$data = @'
Серийный номер: 01 D1 1D 91 2F 01 1D 10 00 00 A5 35 21 B1 01 46
СНИЛС: 33333333333
ОГРН: 4444444444444
ИНН: 555555555555
Адрес, улица: пр. Ленина, 1
Отчество: Иван Иванович
Фамилия: Петров
Электронная почта: abc@xyz.ru
Город: Мирный
Область: 11 Прекрасная область
Страна: RU
Должность: начальник отдела
Подразделение: финансовый отдел
Организация: ООО "Цветочки"
Имя: Петров Иван Иванович
'@

$data -split "`n" | .{
    begin { $resultHashTable = @{} }
    process { $_ -match '(?<name>[^:]*):(?<value>.*)' | Out-Null ; $resultHashTable[$Matches['name']] = $Matches['value'] }
    end { [PSCustomObject]$resultHashTable }
}
```

Хэш преобразуется в CSV. Но это явно плохой код. Есть альтернативные варианты решения?

Answer (score 0):

`$data` представлено строковым типом, в чем можно убедиться вызвав не виртуальный метод `GetType`:

```
$data.GetType()
```

В приведенном примере эта строка преобразуется как раз в хэш, однако делается это, мягко говоря, не лучшим образом. Проще и лучше использовать `ConvertFrom-StringData`:

```
$hash = $data -replace ':', '=' | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

Таким образом получаем хэш, преобразовать который в `.csv` в данном случае можно так:

```
,($hash.Keys -join ',') + ($hash.Values -join ',') |
ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Вместо `ConvertTo-Csv` можно использовать `Export-Csv`.